# Having trouble to configure the php_crack.dll‏ with Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

I'm new to this Phalcon framework and  just started working on it.
It is configured on XAMPP. Phalcon developer Tools also has been setup.

XAMP 1.8.3 for windows 7, 32 bit
PHP 5.5.9
Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture    x86

But, now, I want to configure the php_crack.dll but constantly getting below error.

---

### httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found

### The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll.

### OK

---

### Warning

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp2\php\ext\php_crack.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

---

### OK

Kindly help me out and let me know what I m doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Virda

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a lot of time I found a solution of this problem.
The problem was the php_crack.dll and php version was mismatch, when I downloaded the correct version of crack.dll then the error resolved.

To download the correct version of crack.dll
open the below link and click on DLL under windows section.
According to php version download the file.

http://pecl.php.net/package/crack